# Draw out, throw out, toss out

Tags: word-usage

What is more common in the game of "Rock, Paper and Scissors"?

> She drew out scissors.
>
> She threw out scissors.
>
> She tossed out scissors.

Comment: She **chose** scissors. She **picked** scissors. She **held out** scissors

Comment: I agree with @smock here.

Threw out and tossed out, although *ok*, imply that she lost contact with them (i.e. threw *away*). Drew makes more sense, as one might draw a gun, but in this context, it does sound like she didn't have a choice. I.e. Drew the short straw.

Comment: @Bee I'm not sure "throw out" is bad. For example, in a game of cards I might "throw out an ace." This need not mean to throw _away_; here, "out" means that the card, once hidden in my hand, is now _out_ in the world, revealed. I can imagine someone "throwing out Scissors."

Comment: @TypeIA, I wasn't saying it always means away, I just mean it implies letting go of the thing. As I said, they are both *ok* just to my ear they are more likely used when letting go, e.g. in your example :)

Answer (score 2):

The question was answered in the comments.

> She *chose* scissors. She *picked* scissors. She *held out* scissors – Smock

and

> Threw out and tossed out, although ok, *imply that she lost contact with them* (i.e. threw away). Drew makes more sense, as one might draw a gun, but in this context, it does sound like she didn't have a choice. I.e. Drew the short straw. – Bee

Agreed.

Comment: I might be inclined to remove the word "out" and use "She threw scissors"